You don't have permission to access this resource C# POST request
trying to code a simple parser to get info for my robot. the code is simple. but in return i only get "You don't have permission to access this resource." not the source code like i see in my web browser
using System;
using System.Net.Http;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var endpoint = new Uri("https://www.investing.com/economic-calendar/");
                var result = client.GetAsync(endpoint).Result;
                var json = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            }
        }
    }
}


full data that contains json variable looks like
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You don't have permission to access this resource.</p>
<script>(function(){if (!document.body) return;var js = "window['__CF$cv$params']={r:'88e838692a8f9d5a',t:'MTcxNzUwNzIyNy4yNjMwMDA='};_cpo=document.createElement('script');_cpo.nonce='',_cpo.src='/cdn-cgi/challenge-platform/scripts/jsd/main.js',document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(_cpo);";var _0xh = document.createElement('iframe');_0xh.height = 1;_0xh.width = 1;_0xh.style.position = 'absolute';_0xh.style.top = 0;_0xh.style.left = 0;_0xh.style.border = 'none';_0xh.style.visibility = 'hidden';document.body.appendChild(_0xh);function handler() {var _0xi = _0xh.contentDocument || _0xh.contentWindow.document;if (_0xi) {var _0xj = _0xi.createElement('script');_0xj.innerHTML = js;_0xi.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(_0xj);}}if (document.readyState !== 'loading') {handler();} else if (window.addEventListener) {document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', handler);} else {var prev = document.onreadystatechange || function () {};document.onreadystatechange = function (e) {prev(e);if (document.readyState !== 'loading') {document.onreadystatechange = prev;handler();}};}})();</script></body></html>


can someone help me to get full code like in browser?

Some websites examine the request headers (including the UserAgent) to decide whether the request is coming from a browser or from a bot / crawler.
If you set a real UserAgent then you will receive the same result as if you issue the request from the browser
var client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X x.y; rv:42.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/42.0");
var endpoint = new Uri("https://www.investing.com/economic-calendar/");

var result = await client.GetAsync(endpoint);
var html = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

Also please prefer await over .Result
Dotnet fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/sTbavn

Thanks i already tried like this. but still don't get the main news outlet.

@НиколайБорисов Then you are issuing a request against a wrong url most probably.

i need exactly what inside that window. TIME, CUR, IMP, EVENT etc. The page is about 4700 line of codes. but i only get about 1500 without info from the window. maybe there is some kind of protection. is there any way to avoid it?

@НиколайБорисов Because your request is hitting a website not a webapi that's why the returned response contains HTML and not a JSON/XML/whatever. Please check the developer documentation of the website to learn more about how to fetch/retrieve data from their API (and not through their website).
